# How to chain a ssh, cd, then execution in subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, ssh

I'm trying to execute the following code but it is not working

```
    p = subprocess.Popen("ssh root@IP cd /opt/msys/pe2/bin;./perlscript.pl; -a file.csv", 
                shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

   OR:
   p = subprocess.Popen("ssh root@IP /opt/msys/pe2/bin/perlscript.pl; -a file.csv", 
                shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

The problem with the first is i can seem to chain together commands after ssh.  The 2nd is if i call the file directly the -a arg can't find that file because im not in that directory.  I was hoping to use the cwd parameter to Popen, but it fails because I'm not ssh'd into the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try quoting the command being sent to ssh:

```
subprocess.Popen('ssh root@IP "cd /opt/msys/pe2/bin;./perlscript.pl;" -a file.csv'
```

Otherwise you're telling the local shell to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Subprocess isn't the best tool for this use case.  All the process monitoring options (*wait()* and *terminate()* for example) apply to the local process (the ssh session) and not what is happening with the remote script (the perl script for example).

I use [fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.2.2/index.html) to handle running remote scripts.  It is easier to use than attempting to string together commands with *subprocess*.